# How to specify an Environment systemd directive containing =?

Tags: environment-variables, systemd

I want to specify an `Environment` `systemd` directive containing `=`, e.g.

```
Environment=CATALINA_OPTS=-Dappserver.home=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current -Dappserver.base=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current
```

and get the error

```
[/lib/systemd/system/archiva.service:10] Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: CATALINA_OPTS=-Dappserver.home\=/var/lib/archiva/apache
```

in `journalctl -xe`. I tried to quote with `"` and `'` and to escape `=` with `\` without success. This seems undocumented.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think your problem is due the space in the environment variable's contents. Looking at the examples from [the systemd docs](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), an assignment should be a single string:

> Example:
>
> ```
> Environment="ONE=one" 'TWO=two two'
> ExecStart=/bin/echo $ONE $TWO ${TWO}
> ```
>
> This will execute /bin/echo with four arguments: `one`, `two`, `two`,
>   and `two two`.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Environment=ONE='one' "TWO='two two' too" THREE=
> ExecStart=/bin/echo ${ONE} ${TWO} ${THREE}
> ExecStart=/bin/echo $ONE $TWO $THREE
> ```
>
> This results in echo being called twice, the first time with arguments
>   `'one'`, `'two two' too`, , and the second time with arguments
>   `one`, `two two`, `too`.

I tested this with the following service (note the quotes around the entire assignment):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Daemon

[Service]
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Dappserver.home=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current -Dappserver.base=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current'
ExecStart=/bin/echo ${CATALINA_OPTS}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And got the desired output in `journalctl`:

```
Apr 26 08:19:29 laptop echo[28439]: -Dappserver.home=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current -Dappserver.base=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current
```

---

Of course, it would be simpler to use `EnvironmentFile` instead. Replacing the `Environment` with the following gave the same desired result:

```
EnvironmentFile=/tmp/foo
```

Where `/tmp/foo` contained (note the lack of quotes):

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Dappserver.home=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current -Dappserver.base=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current
```

Comment: When it comes to quoting quotes (e.g. by using `CATALINA_OPTS` in `systemd` environment for Apache `tomcat` 7.0.61) using `EnvironmentFile` really is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: What is the standard/ convention directory for keeping an EnvironmentFile on Ubuntu?  On other systems I've seen /etc/sysconfig/

Comment: @Davos a reasonable place would be `/etc/default`. Files there have been historically used for placing environment variables for corresponding init scripts.

Comment: I have this file already on my system /etc/environment which contains a PATH variable, would appending to that be sensible?

Comment: @Davos that's systemwide. If there's no problem with the variable being set for practically every process, sure. Note that `/etc/environment` is not processed by a shell; aside from simple variable assignment, its syntax is very different from the systemd syntax noted above or general shell syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, that's very helpful. I'll use something like /etc/default/<servicename> as the EnvironmentFile for this.

Comment: systemd is so nice.....

Comment: Is it possible to set a variable with a double quote in the value?

Comment: @lav quoting the value with single quotes should work, I guess, but I haven't tested it

Comment: For demonstrations, it would be better to use something like `printf "[%s]\n" $ONE $TWO` instead of `echo` to make it more apparent how arguments are interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the accepted answer says, if you put your environment variables into a drop-in file, then you need to use the following syntax to make sure they are not all treated as one argument to your program:

### *env.conf* drop-in file

```
[Service]
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Dappserver.home=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current -Dappserver.base=/var/lib/archiva/apache-tomcat-current'
```

### unit.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/echo $CATALINA_OPTS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't know why using just `$ENV_NAME` worked for me, and `${ENV_NAME}` didn't, and I couldn't find anything documenting this difference. All I can say is that `$ENV_NAME` syntax worked to treat each argument in the variable which is separated by space, as distinct arguments, whereas the `${ENV_NAME}`, treated them all as one argument.

Maybe using `echo` is not the best way to tell this difference. I suggest anyone looking to test it to use something like `/usr/bin/printf "%s\n" ${ENV_NAME}` vs `/usr/bin/printf "%s\n" $ENV_NAME`, and see what they get.

#### Creating drop-in files

One can create a drop-in file by using the `edit` command for systemctl. For example in the case of this question, the command would be:

```sh
sudo systemctl edit archiva.service
```

You can also create one like I did above by adding a custom file to `/lib/systemd/system/archiva.service.d/` folder

---

### EDIT

I found the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) on observed environmental variable behavior, thanks to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57423141/2089675):

> Basic environment variable substitution is supported. Use "${FOO}" as
> part of a word, or as a word of its own, on the command line, in which
> case it will be erased and replaced by the exact value of the
> environment variable (if any) including all whitespace it contains,
> always resulting in exactly a single argument. Use "$FOO" as a
> separate word on the command line, in which case it will be replaced
> by the value of the environment variable split at whitespace,
> resulting in zero or more arguments. For this type of expansion,
> quotes are respected when splitting into words, and afterwards
> removed.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative solution

"C escapes supported in command lines and environment variables"

- "\n" newline
- "\r" carriage return
- "\t" tab
- "\v" vertical tab
- "\" backslash
- """ double quotation mark
- "'" single quotation mark
- "\s" space
- "\xxx"   character number xx in hexadecimal encoding
- "\nnn"   character number nnn in octal encoding

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html